# Extracting data from Airtasker using beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from this website - https://www.airtasker.com/users/brad-n-11346775/.

So far, I have managed to extract everything except the **license number**. The problem I'm facing is bizarre as the license number is in the form of text. I was able to extract everything else like the Name, Address etc. For example, to extract the Name, I just did this:

```
name.append(pro.find('div', class_= 'name').text)
```

And it works just fine.

This is what I have tried to do, but I'm getting the output as **None**

```
license_number.append(pro.find('div', class_= 'sub-text'))
```

When I do :

```
license_number.append(pro.find('div', class_= 'sub-text').text)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

That means it does not recognise the license number as a text, even though it is a text.

Can someone please give me a workable solution and please tell me what am I doing wrong???
Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The badge with the license number is added to the `HTML` dynamically from a `Boostrap JSON` that sits in one of the `<script>` tags.

You can find the tag with `bs4` and scoop out the data with `regex` and parse it with `json`.

Here's how:

```python
import ast
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.airtasker.com/users/brad-n-11346775/").text
scripts = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml").find_all("script")[-4]
bootstrap_JSON = json.loads(
    ast.literal_eval(re.search(r"parse\((.*)\)", scripts.string).group(1))
)
print(bootstrap_JSON["profile"]["badges"]["electrical_vic"]["reference_code"])
```

Output:

```
Licence No. 28661
```

Comment: This works , Thank You :) I'm very new to BeautifulSoup :)